# How to tell that common subexpression elimination is happening or not in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-optimization

Let's say I have a naively implemented function like this:

```
quadratic a b c = (ans1, ans2)
  where
    ans1 = ((-b) + sqrt (b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
    ans2 = ((-b) - sqrt (b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
```

There are multiple identical subexpressions. How can I tell without reading core that common subexpression elimination is happening or not and to which parts of this?

Comment: I think "by reading core" is the answer. Why don't you want to do that? You may be able to guess by inserting functions from `Debug.Trace`, but I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: @jberryman Are there rules of thumb that indicate what code is likely or not likely to be optimized?

Comment: Unrelated, but nondeterminism is modeled with lists, not tuples. `quadratic a b c = [ans1, ans2] where ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `trace` might tell you as demonstrated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920200/how-to-prevent-common-sub-expression-elimination-cse-with-ghc).

```
import Debug.Trace

quadratic a b c = (ans1, ans2)
  where
    ans1 = ((-b) + tr1 (sqrt (b * b - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
    ans2 = ((-b) - tr2 (sqrt (b * b - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
    tr1 = trace "ans1"
    tr2 = trace "ans2"

main = print $ quadratic 1 10 3
```

Compiling this with `-O2` or `-O3` shows both `ans1` and `ans2` in the trace output indicating that GHC did not perform the CSE. You get similar
results if you use `tr1` in both places.

The Haskell Wiki mentions that GHC only performs CSE in limited
circumstances -  [(link)](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Common_subexpression_elimination) - and that you are advised to perform
it yourself if you want to make sure it happens.